# Cannot understand the bound of Lagrangian parameter in SMO

Tags: svm, lagrange-multipliers

I'm trying to understand SMO, but stuck to the part of bound for Lagrangian parameters.

In the SMO paper(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/1998/04/sequential-minimal-optimization.pdf), it says that the linear equality constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i y_i=0$ causes the $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ lies on diagonal line.

I cannot understand this part. What is the meaning of a diagonal line and why they should lie on it?

The below figure is used to explain this on paper, but it cannot serve any information to me...

[image]

In summary,

(1) What is the meaning of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ lie on diagonal line?

(2) Why the bound for $\alpha_2$ is

$L = \max(0, \alpha_2 - \alpha_1), H = \min(C, C + \alpha_2 - \alpha_1)$ (When $y_2 \neq y_1$)

$L = \max(0, \alpha_2 + \alpha_1 - C), H = \min(C, \alpha_2 + \alpha_1)$ (When $y_2 = y_1$)

Comment: The crucial facts are (1) "The value yi is +1 for the positive examples in a class and –1 for the negative examples" and (2) these are only two of the $n$ Lagrange multipliers: $k$ is the contribution of the linear equality constraint due to the remaining $n-2$ multipliers.

Comment: @whuber Oh, thank you. I missed that $y$ can be $1$ and $-1$ as you told me. But I still cannot understand why the bound is created like that. Can you give me some help?

Comment: When $y_1=-1,$ negate all the $y_i$--this doesn't change the constraint.  It leads to two cases. The first is $y_2 = 1.$ Write the constraint as $$0 = y_1\alpha_1+y_2\alpha_2+\sum_{i=3}^n y_i\alpha_i = \alpha_1+\alpha_2 - k$$ where $k = -\sum_{i=3} y_i\alpha_i.$ That's the situation in the right panel. The second case $y_2=-1$ gives the situation in the left panel.

Comment: @whuber Thanks a lot!